# Invoke enum in Java

Tags: java, enums, invoke

Suppose I have a number of fields (`String` or `int`) in my `Java` enum, and I want to get a field value by its name , dynamically.

```
public enum Code {

    FIRST("valueForFirst"),
    SECOND("valueForSecond");
    // etc
}
```

Then I get the name of the field which I want:

```
String fieldName = getEnumFieldName(); // can be: "FIRST" or "SECOND" 
// now get "fieldName"'s value from Code
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: I think I was not clear. I am interested in invoke of this enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Enum.valueOf();` such as:

```
Code c = Code.valueOf(Code.class, fieldName);
```

Comment: @Madrugada Specifying `Code.class` is reduntant.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your enum like this :

```
public enum Code {

    private String value;

    public Code(String value) {
       this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
       return value;
    }

    FIRST("valueForFirst"),
    SECOND("valueForSecond");
}
```

and then use it like this :

```
Code code = Code.FIRST;
String val = code.getValue();
```

or like this :

```
String key = "FIRST";
Code code = Code.valueOf(key);
String val = code.getValue();
```

If you want to get "FIRST" from a Code, just do

```
String name = code.name();
```

Comment: Why did somebody downvote ? Is that one of those infamous "tactical downvotes" ?

Comment: @Madrugada Is something missing in my answer ?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to load dynamically...see lynks's answer, Sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the name of your field from somewhere else in string form, you can use `valueOf()` method to get Enum instance.. But, first you would need to convert the string in all uppercase..

```
String fieldName = getEnumFieldName();
Code first = Code.valueOf(fieldName);
String value = first.getValue();
```

**Go through this tutorial** - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html for more information on how to use `Enums`..

Comment: thank you. The thing is that I dont know whether fieldName will be "FIRST" or "SECOND", it comes dynamically.

Comment: If the field name is dynamic (and I don't know how it could be or why this is a good idea) you can use reflections to look at which fields the enum provides.

Comment: @Madrugada.. How are you getting it?? Dynamically?

Comment: @Madrugada.. Look at my edited post.. Is this what you want??

Comment: @Madrugada.. You can go through the tutorial link I gave to better understand the working of Enums..

Comment: thanks for the tutorial. I thought it's something more complicated about this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `valueOf()` method on the enum.

```
String fieldName = "FIRST"; // or "SECOND" 
Code c = Code.valueOf(fieldName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pattern which I use:

```
enum X {
    A("a"), B("b"), ...;

    private final static Map<String,X> MAP = new HashMap<String,X>();
    static {
        for( X elem: X.values() ) {
            if( null != MAP.put( elem.getValue(), elem ) ) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Duplicate value " + elem.getValue() );
            }
        }
    }

    private final String value;

    private X(String value) { this.value = value; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }

    // You may want to throw an error here if the map doesn't contain the key
    public static X byValue( String value ) { return MAP.get( value ); } 
}
```

It looks a bit odd to access the instances of the `enum` type in a `static` block inside of the `enum` declaration but this code works.

In your case, the could would look like so:

```
String fieldName = Code.valueOf(Code.class).getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public enum Code {

        FIRST("valueForFirst"),
        SECOND("valueForSecond");

    }

    public class Test{

       Code c;

       public static void main(String[] args){

        Test t = new Test();

        String val = t.c.FIRST.getValue();



        }

  }
```